# How to get the first TRUE value in an excel array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

In an Excel array formula - when I try to return the first `TRUE` value from an array using the `IF` formula, it works as expected if `TRUE` is the first entry in the array, but not if `TRUE` appears later

For example, this works and returns "a"

```
=IF({TRUE,FALSE},{"a","b"})
```

But this does not work as I would expect - and returns `FALSE`

```
=IF({FALSE,TRUE},{"a","b"})
```

What is the right way to get to "b" in this case?

**EDIT**

The question I have is - if I have a "logical condition" array with *exactly* one `TRUE` value, how do I return the value corresponding to the `TRUE`.

With numeric values, I can use the `SMALL` function, for example -

```
=SMALL(IF({FALSE,TRUE},{1,4}),1)
```

This returns 4. Is there something equivalent that I can use if I have `{"a", "b"}` instead of `{1, 4}` above.

Comment: A cell can only hold one value and not an array, your formula returns an array.  The first `{"a",FALSE}`, the second `{FALSE,"b"}` and as such it returns the first value in the array to the cell in which you put the formula.

Comment: The question is what is the end result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways:

- with O360:

  ```
   =XLOOKUP(TRUE,{FALSE,TRUE},{"a","b"})
  ```
- earlier versions:

  ```
  =HLOOKUP(TRUE,{FALSE,TRUE;"a","b"},2,0)
  =INDEX({"a","b"},MATCH(TRUE,{FALSE,TRUE},0))
  ```